# Javascript for google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

So i'm using google app script and creating macros for my spreadsheet.
I'm using a jira add on and when I go and check the script. It only shows showPanel with no actions on what is being done in the panel.

```js
function jirarefresh2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('All Issues Data Sheet'), true);
  showPanel();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Overdue Issue Data Sheet'), true);
  showPanel();
};
```

inside the show panel is supposed to close [x] one tab then to click on a button to refresh the issue. But it's not showing here.

Comment: Hello, I think you'll need to include more detail to understand what is happening. What is `showPanel`? What "actions" do you mean? What do you mean by `supposed to close [x]` ? What issues are you talking about? See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, why are there `<br>` in your code? Where are you trying to run the code from?